# Cannot resolve symbol 'R' after updating android plugin version (gradle version) to 3.3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, r.java-file

I changed my android plugin version to latest i.e. 3.3.0 and after syncing the project, the reference to R class has been lost and turned into red saying 'Cannot resolve symbol 'R''.

Comment: Go to File>>> Invalidate Cache and Restart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: I had the same issue after updating the plugin version to 3.3.0, if you haven't already, update android studio to the latest version. That fixed it for me

Comment: @Zach Thank you that worked for me. after updating android studio, it automatically update the gradle version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

1. `Build > Clean Project` and then `Build > Rebuild Project`.
2. `File > Invalidate caches`

Answer (score 0):

I has updated my android studio version and after that were lots of errors. I had to reinstall android studio and after that all errors vanished. This does not required lots of time