# cannot find R.id.exo_pause after upgrading Gradle plugin from 7.4.2

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am experiencing a problem in android studio in my project. The resource ids [exo_play and exo_pause](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerControlView.html)  cannot be found if I upgrade **Gradle Plugin version**  from **7.4.2 to 8+**. It has nothing to do with the Exoplayer version. Now my project is running on gradle version 8.2.1 and g plugin version 7.4.2. But **if I upgrade plugin version it doesn't work**

Answer (score 0):

The following should solve your problem:

`Build > Clean Project` and then `Build > Rebuild Project.`

Subsequently,

```
File > Invalidate caches
```

You can refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54348055/19119712

and the release notes: [https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin?buildsystem=ndk-build#updating-gradle:~:text=Was%20this%20helpful%3F-,Android%20Gradle%20plugin%20release%20notes,-bookmark_border](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin?buildsystem=ndk-build#updating-gradle:%7E:text=Was%20this%20helpful%3F-,Android%20Gradle%20plugin%20release%20notes,-bookmark_border)

Let me know whether or not the change worked, if/when you make the change. In case it doesn't, you can also try updating your android studio. Good luck!

Comment: Nope, It doesn't. These resource ids are not found in the newest gradle version. But if i downgrade they are found. It has nothing to do with exoplayer lib version